# recursion not working properly in nodejs typescript async method

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, asynchronous, recursion

I have a async method in nodejs where i am trying to limit a api call above a certain limit,here is my code:

```
async initializeVideo() {
      console.log(this.transcodingRetryCounter)
      if (this.transcodingRetryCounter >= this.transcodingRetryLimit) {
         console.log('Transcoding Retry limit reached,Stopping the transcoding');
         return;
      }
      this.player = videojs(
        this.$refs.videoPlayer,
        this.options,
        function onPlayerReady() {
          console.log('Playing on transcoded video')
        }
      )
      this.player.on('error', () => {
        console.log('error')
        console.log(this.player.error())
        this.transcodingStatus = TRANSCODING_STATUS.REMAINING
        this.transcodingRetryCounter++;
        this.initializeVideo()
        VideoService.checkTranscodingError(this.$route.params.id)
      })
      this.player.ready(() => {
        console.log('ready hu') // not going inside usage
        this.player.tech().on('usage', e => {.  // I am not reaching inside.
          if (e.name === 'vhs-rendition-blacklisted') {
            console.log('usage hu')
            this.transcodingStatus = TRANSCODING_STATUS.REMAINING
            this.transcodingRetryCounter++;
            this.initializeVideo()
            this.player.play()
            VideoService.checkTranscodingError(this.$route.params.id)
          }
        })
      })
      if (this.transcodingStatus !== TRANSCODING_STATUS.COMPLETED) {
        this.player.src({
          type: 'video/mp4',
          src: this.src
        })
        console.log('Playing video directly from bucket')
      }
      this.player.hlsQualitySelector = videojsqualityselector
      this.player.hlsQualitySelector({
        displayCurrentQuality: true
      })
      
    }
```

transcodingRetryCounter is set to 0 and transcodingRetryLimit is set to 3 at first using:

```
data() {
    return {
      player: null,
      transcodingRetryLimit: 3,
      transcodingRetryCounter: 0
    }
  }
```

but when i am printing the counter using `console.log(transcodingRetryCounter)`,its going till 6 and then stopping even if it shd stop at 3.

whats the issue here?

Comment: You are in no way checking if any in-flight invocations are complete before queueing up new ones. So if e.g. your player on error callback is called a number of times in quick succession, you will end up with any number of concurrent calls to your async method which happen after the counter bumps which means that they can all return early. You need to completely restructure your code so you can await the previous invocation before beginning a new one.